# how do i stop my sticky footer being pushed below the fold

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have tried to implement one of bootstraps sticky footers into my cms. The sticky footer is fine until i add images to it which then the copyright note gets pushed below the fold.

You can see it here-> http://newrycreates.com/contact

What it looks like:

[image: What it looks like]

What it should look like:

[image: what it should like]

Comment: Please include code in your question, once you fix your page that link will become useless. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. By all means provide a functional example on a site like jsFiddle.net **in addition** to code in the quetion

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Developer tools in Chrome or Firebug for Firefox to hel debug this issue. A quick look at you elements shows the footer has a set height of 80px yet the image is 100px high. Change the height of your footer appropriatly.

You have positioned the base of the footer at the bottom of the page, however the contetns of the footer overflow this, hence your problem. The [MDN on  css overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) adds some light to this.